# Unable to read beyond the end of the stream

Tags: java, c#, socket

Estava tentando criar uma conexão soquetes entre Java e C#, sendo Java o cliente e C# o servidor.

Porém quando uso BinaryReader para ler os dados, retorna um erro:

> Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.

Trecho do código C# que faz a leitura:

```
Console.WriteLine("Iniciando...");
IPEndPoint ipp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.173.1"), 5000);
tccp=new TcpListener(ipp);
tccp.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Conexão TCP iniciada, ip : 127.0.0.1, porta: 4567");

doidaco = tccp.AcceptSocket();
newton = new NetworkStream(doidaco);
rr = new BinaryReader(newton);

string mensagem="";
do{
     mensagem = rr.ReadString();
    Console.WriteLine("\nMensagem do cliente: "+mensagem);

}while(doidaco.Connected);
```

Código completo C#: http://pastebin.com/m2Vpznts

O código de Java que está enviando a mensagem pelo soquete é o seguinte:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    socket = new Socket("192.168.173.1", 5000);
    Scanner sca = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
    PrintWriter ee = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
    ee.println("Hello!");
    System.out.println("Mensagem enviada.");
    ee.close();
    System.out.println("Conexão encerrada.");
    sca.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

Código Java: http://pastebin.com/2ewZtxVk

Comment: Tenho um exemplo de código que utiliza apenas Sockets. Te serve? Posso colocar isso na resposta?

Comment: Bom, eu gostaria de enviar uma mensagem soquete 'Hello' do client java (Android), para um servidor C#. Caso tenha alguma relação seria um favor.

Comment: Acho que a resposta abaixo já deu certo! :) Ainda quer o exemplo só com `Socket` do lado lado do servidor, sem `TcpListener`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu problema é que o formato da mensagem escrita no *socket* (código em java) é diferente do formato esperado no leitor (código em C#). A chamada a `ee.println("Hello!");` vai escrever os bytes relativos à string "Hello!" (0x48 0x65 0x6C 0x6C 0x6F 0x21) seguidos do *line feed* (0x0A ou 0x0D).

A chamada a `BinaryReader.ReadString`, no entanto, espera que o primeiro byte da mensagem indique o tamanho da string (vide [documentação do MSDN para este método](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Então quando o `BinaryReader` começa a ler a string, ele vê o "tamanho" de 0x48 e tenta ler mais 0x48 (72) bytes da stream - e não existe esta quantidade de bytes, razão pela qual você recebe o erro que você mencionou.

Se você quer usar o `println` para escrever a string pelo lado de java, considere ler os bytes no receptor até encontrar o fim da linha (0x0A / 0x0D). Uma alternativa é usar um `StreamReader` e o método `ReadToEnd()` para ler tudo o que o cliente enviou.

```
var clientSocket = tccp.AcceptSocket();
var clientSocketStream = new NetworkStream(clientSocket);
var streamReader = new StreamReader(clientSocketStream);

string mensagem = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine("Mensagem do cliente: " + mensagem);
```

Comment: Eu não entendo muito essas coisas, eu teria alguma forma de solucionar?

Comment: Editei a resposta com uma opção de como resolver.

Comment: Funcionou! Eu gostaria de saber se há algum método de ele ficar atualizando, isto é, a cada mensagem que o cliente enviar ele escreva no chat.

Comment: Em vez de usar o `ReadToEnd` dá uma olhada nos outros métodos da classe `StreamReader`; talvez o `ReadLine` faça o que você precisa.